# Как обезопасить config.php

Tags: php

Только начинаю понемножку осваивать PHP и сразу назрел вопрос, как обезопасить файл config.php?

В данный момент сам файл выглядит так:

```
<?

    session_start();

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $vk_config['client_id'] = '';
    $vk_config['client_secret'] = '';
    $vk_config['redirect_uri'] = '';
    $vk_config['v'] = '';

?>
```

Если нужно получить данные в каком то месте, подключаю через include и подставляю переменную с нужным мне ключом:

```
vk_authorize($vk_config['client_id'], $vk_config['redirect_uri'], $vk_config['v']);
```

Пример в функции:

```
function vk_authorize($client_id, $redirect_uri, $v) {
    $params = array (
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
        'display'       => 'page',
        'scope'         => 'email',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'v'             => $v
    );
    echo '<a class="vk-authorize" href="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)) . '">Аутентификация</a>';
}
```

Собственно кто что может посоветовать с точки зрения безопасности?

Comment: А от чего его обезопасить?Даже если его подключит сторонний сервер,то не получит переменных внутри.Или если зайдёт прямо точно по адресу на файл,то злоумышленика будет ожидать разочарование.

Comment: Maksym, я не очень осведомлен во все нюансы - поэтому и задал такой вопрос.

Comment: Стоит выкинуть короткие теги для избежания проблем с миграцией. В остальном все ок.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, то все содержимое файла выводится в браузер.
В этом случае непонятно, от чего этот файл следует защищать.

В общем, случае, страдать конспиареей не стоит, и ни от чего специально файлы защищать не нужно.

В появлением опыта, придет понимание того как строить архитектуру сайта, размещая все программные файлы вне корня веб-сервера. Но это больше вопрос архитектуры, чем безопасности.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду? Можно где-то почитать про такую архитеутуру?

Comment: Что значить все содержимое файла выводится в браузер? Оно как раз и не выводится, так как показывать кому либо защищенный ключ строго запрещено. P.S. Плюс в будущем там будет пароль от БД, который тоже показывать нельзя.

Comment: Ну так он и так никому не показывается, об этом еще в самом начале в комментах сказали

Answer (score 1):

Выносите все ваши пароли и настройки за папку public_html

Answer (score 0):

Поместите файл конфигурации в директорию `/includes` и добавьте в эту директорию файл `.htaccess` с содержимым

```
Require all denied
```

т.е. заперт доступа на уровне сервера, в данном случае для Apache 2.4

Comment: Этого будет достаточно?

Comment: @РодионПоляков да, при прямом запросе в браузере адреса `example.com/includes/config.php` сервер выдаст ошибку `403 Forbidden` при этом вы сможете без проблем включать файл с помощью конструкций `include/require` в свои скрипты. Т.е. все системные файлы, к которым вы не хотите давать доступ извне можно помещать в эту директорию. Но, вообще, если при запросе этого файла извне исполнение его кода не приведет к каким-либо действиям, например, запись данных в БД, то можно оставить как есть, иначе любой желающий сможет обращаться к нему и писать данные в БД.